# MVC Identity failed with the operating system error 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have Created MVC project in Visual studio 2015 .when i try to register user program throw following error.

> Directory lookup for the file "c:\users\faheem\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\App_Data\aspnet-WebApplication4-20160311011345.mdf"
>   failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.). CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  The executable does not have permissions to that directory.  You need to add the correct permissions for the account that the executable is running as (used to be `IIS_User` - not sure if still/was correct) to that folder.

Comment: Start VS as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

`System error 5` means you didn't run `Visual Studio` in administrator mode. Right click the program and click on `Run as administrator`.